# How can I change the color CSS property of an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How do you change CSS in jQuery? I just want the font color for "Valid VIN" to be red and this does not work:

```
$("#result").html(<font color="red">"Valid VIN"</font>);
```

Comment: Can you provide the full HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

`.css()` can be used in one of two ways. You can pass two string parameters, a CSS property and a value, or you can pass one object parameter with key (CSS property) and value (CSS value) pairs:

```
$('#result').css('color', 'red');
// or
$('#result').css({color: 'red'});
```

If you were targeting the `<font>` tag inside then:

```
$('#result font').css('color', 'red');
```

**Note:** I should point out that the `<font>` tag [is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), so there's that.

You can also pass a function to set a CSS value:

```
$('#result').css('color', function(){
   return '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16); //A random colour
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `font` tag has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You must change the attribute value of the font tag

```
$('#result font').attr('color' , 'red');
```